# Receiving integral sign when using confirm dialog in atom-editor

Tags: atom-editor

For some reason, when I use the following code in package I'm trying to contribute to, an integral sign (∫) appears in the active document when a button is selected on the dialog.

```
checkAutoSave: ()->
  if atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().isModified()
    if atom.config.get('build.saveOnBuild') is true
      atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().save()
      return 1
    else if atom.config.get('build.promptToSaveOnBuild') is true
      diaDirection = atom.confirm
        message: 'Do you want to save the current file before building?'
        detailedMessage: 'This message can be turned off in the Build settings.'
        buttons: ['Yes', 'No', 'Cancel Build']
      switch diaDirection
        when 0
          atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().save()
          return 1
        when 1
          return 0
        when 2
          return -1
  else #Current File wasn't changed.
    return 0
```

I have tried narrowing it down and I am 100% it has something to do with the dialog.  The problem does not exists without the dialog call.  The Integral sign appears in the document regardless of the button pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem a while ago - see [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/keyboard-shortcut-inserts-character-into-editor-when-showing-alert/11037) for more details.

The action I wanted to trigger in the editor was bound to Ctrl+Alt+B, which by default inserts the integral sign on Mac OS X. The integral sign was inserted into the currently open document when I opened a standard alert box from my package's code.

I didn't found out why, but it looks similar to your problem. In the end, I resolved it by removing the alert and using an Atom view instead for showing the message. As soon as I did this, the integral sign was no longer inserted into the document.

It looks like there's an issue with the key binding and preventing event propagation when using some dialogs. In some cases, the key event is handed to the OS and it inserts the character associated with the pressed key.

Maybe you can try using an Atom view instead of the confirm dialog, and it will resolve your issue as well.

Comment: I didn't even check to see the OS X key bindings.